# (SQL Server) How to defragment indexes with LOBs?

Tags: sql-server, indexing, fragmentation, defragmentation

In SQL Server, are there some points on defragmenting indexes with LOBs? Such as `text, ntext, image, varchar(max), nvarchar(max), varbinary(max), xml`.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You can't do online index rebuilds
- You have the option LOB_COMPACTION. It does exactly that if ON

Otherwise, [nothing special](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188388.aspx)

I'd consider doing a LOB_COMPACTION less frequently but both options comes down to your maintenance windows duration pretty much